# Create a column with cumulative calculation in R

Tags: r

[image]

1- Group the Table by Part Number and Order Number
2- Sort the group created by On Time Start on Ascending order
3- See the picture attached ,  I need to create a Cum Total Span. The operations are in Days (not in hour)

Here is a sample of the code.  Thanks

```
structure(list(Order = c("100016572", "100016572", "100016572", 
"100049101", "100049101", "100049101", "100049101", "100049101", 
"100049101", "100049101"), Op = c(9997, 9997, 9997, 8391, 8392, 
8393, 8394, 8395, 8396, 8397), `Op Desc` = c("PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", 
"PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", "PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", 
"ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", "MACHINE SHOP IAW 200365779", 
"ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", "PP&C REWORK IAW 200365779", 
"INSPECT IAW 200365779", "ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", "PP&C REWORK IAW 200365779"
), `Part No` = c("2352841G1-516", "2352841G1-516", "2352841G1-516", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", "2352841G1", 
"2352841G1", "2352841G1"), WBS = c("G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", 
"G-CUST-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", 
"G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01", "G-6M76-01"), `Work Cntr` = c("26801702", 
"26801702", "26801702", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", 
"CHRI0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000"), `On Time Start` = structure(c(1557852668.803, 
1557852668.803, 1557852668.803, 1579215738.477, 1579279874.08, 
1579598294.2, 1579625528.097, 1579690071.267, 1583883648.167, 
1584029686.74), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    `On Time Comp` = structure(c(1585156034.313, 1585156034.313, 
    1585156034.313, 1579216621.723, 1579285486.47, 1579605490.21, 
    1579626040.097, 1583876924.857, 1584012522.213, 1584029801.71
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Span_CDay = structure(c(316.011174884259, 
    316.011174884259, 316.011174884259, 0.0102227546302257, 0.0649582175938068, 
    0.0832871527776674, 0.00592592592592593, 48.4589535879647, 
    1.49159775462967, 0.00133067129662743), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(Order = c("100016572", "100049101"
), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the 'Span_CDay' column to `numeric` before doing the `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   arrange(Order, `Part No`, `On Time Start`) %>% 
   group_by(Order, `Part No`) %>%
   mutate(CSum_Span_CDay = cumsum(as.numeric(Span_CDay)))
```

#### Update

If we want to get the difference between the `first` element of 'On Time Start' and the 'On Time Comp' after `arrange`ing the columns

```
df1 %>% 
   arrange(Order, `Part No`, `On Time Start`) %>% 
   group_by(Order, `Part No`) %>%
   mutate(Diff_span = as.numeric(difftime(`On Time Comp`, 
        first(`On Time Start`), units = 'days')),
      Cum_Diff_span = cumsum(Diff_span))
```

Comment: The code works great, but I am not trying to do a cum on span days. In the picture you can see what I need. The table I made in the right side. Thanks

Comment: @JavierPrieto You want to do the `cumsum` or just the difference between the first element of start and all elements of complete

Comment: @JavierPrieto please check the updated code.

Comment: I think it is working but the calculation are in seconds , I believe. How can I make them days in the same line of code?

Comment: @JavierPrieto you can use `difftime`, updated the post

Comment: Diff_Span is now in Days, however , Cum_Diff_span still in minutes or seconds. I can try difftime

Comment: @JavierPrieto Please check the updated post with `difftime` in my post